# Auth::login() is not working as expected in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-8

There is a problem when I want to login, even though I have entered the email & pass correctly. But, still can't login.

This my route

```php
Route::get('/', [LoginController::class, 'index']); 
Route::post('/', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate']);
```

This my controller

```php
public function authenticate(Request $request){
    $credentials = $request -> validate([
        'email' => 'required|email:dns',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)){
        $request -> session()->regenerate();

        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
    }
    return back()-> with('loginError', 'Wah, ada yang salah nih bestie :(');
}
```

When I try this `dd(Auth::attempt($credentials));` it returns `false`, even though the email & pass is correct and already in the database.

So, where is the error?

Comment: Show us your `view` code. Also check the login fields names.

Comment: Can you explain whether the password is hashed in the registration or not?
If not, you should hash with Hash :: make

Comment: how did your password get INTO the database?

Answer (score 0):

Check the email and password sent from your login view by doing a simple check in your authenticate method:

```
dd($email, $password)
```

If it is ok, then maybe passwords are not being hashed in users table.